# Ejecutar archivo Python desde un archivo PHP

Tags: php, python, apache

quisiera que me ayudaran con un problema que tengo con mi codigo, el cual eh estado revisando mucho pero no puedo solucionarlo, este es mi programa en php, el cual se ejecuta en un servidor apache (utilizando raspberry pi 3 B), tambien les dejare mi programa de python, el objetivo del programa es controlar el giro de un motor, y su velocidad, pero no logro ejecutar el archivo python, pero si lo ejecuto desde la terminal de comandos, y coloco lo siguiente:

```
cd /var/www/html
python motorpwm.py 100 1 0 0
```

el led (primero lo estoy probando con un led) enciende, y si el numero varia en lugar de 100, si cambia su intensidad, pero si lo trato de ejecutar desde php, no pasa nada físicamente con el led, aun cuando los echo si imprimen los valores correspondientes de 'x', 'y', 'z' y 'a'.

```
<?php
     $x=$_GET['velocidad'];
      if(isset($_GET['der'])){
            $y=1;
            $z=0;
            $a=0;

        }elseif(isset($_GET['izq'])){
             $z=1;
             $y=0;
             $a=0;
          }elseif(isset($_GET['alto'])){
             $z=0;
             $y=0;
             $a=2;
          }
$instruccion=("python /var/www/html/motorpwm.py ".$x." ".$y." ".$z." ".$a);
/*tambien lo probe quitando el /var/www/html ya que se encuentran en la misma carpeta*/
echo $instruccion;      
$resultado=shell_exec($instruccion);
echo $resultado;
     ?>
```

'x' es la velocidad del motor que el usuario inserta, 'der' es cuando el usuario presiona el botón que hace girar el motor a la derecha, 'izq' el botón de la izquierda, y 'alto' es el botón para parar el motor. El echo $instruccion si imprime el valor de $instruccion, y el echo $resultado si imprime los valores de 'x', y', 'z' y 'a'. aquí les dejo mi programa de python.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import sys
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)  
pwm = GPIO.PWM(12, 100)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT) 
pwm2 = GPIO.PWM(11, 100)
pwm2.start(0)
vel= float(sys.argv[1])
p1= int(sys.argv[2])
p2=int(sys.argv[3])
p3=int(sys.argv[4])
print(vel)
print(p1)
print(p2)
print(p3)

while p3!=2:
 if p1==1:
    pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(vel)
    pwm2.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
 elif p2==1:
    pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
    pwm2.ChangeDutyCycle(vel)

print("fin")
pwm.stop()
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Creo que mi problema no esta tanto en el archivo de python, ya que este si corre desde la linea de comando, mas bien en el archivo php, el cual es el que no ejecuta el archivo python. Quiero aclarar que el archivo python si es 'ejecutable', y tiene los permisos del usuario www:data, al igual que la carpeta donde se encuentran los dos archivos, también quiero aclarar que ambos los archivos php y python se encuentran juntos en la dirección /var/www/html

Comment: Agrega más datos a la pregunta ¿Podrías pasar captura de lo que imprime cuando ejecutas de una manera y cuando lo hace de la otra? También sería recomendable que indicases las versiones de php y Python que uses.

Answer (score 2):

Probablemente, `shell_exec()` de PHP no está creando el ambiente completo que requiere el interpretador de Python para ejecutar tu programa. Intenta usar rutas absolutas para localizar el interpretador:

`shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/python /var/www/programa.py')`

Tal vez debas incluso modificar tu programa en Python para de manera que puedas definir las rutas a las librerías adicionales que incluyes, ya que no hay un ambiente de ejecución completo como cuando corres el programa desde tu *shell*

Por otro lado supongo que estás usando Apache+PHP para generar tu interfaz de usuario con HTML y procesar las formas donde capturas los parámetros. Es como usar un tractocamión con doble semiremolque para mover una caja de zapatos a dos metros de distancia .

Con unas pocas modificaciones podrás usar el servidor web integrado de Python desde tu mismo programa para mostrar tu interfaz web, procesar las formas y ejecutar los comandos todo desde un solo programa mucho más ligero. Tu Raspberry PI te lo agradecerá

**edit:** Algunas mejoras y sugerencias a tu codigo, **[tambien en este gist](https://gist.github.com/hlecuanda/e83174998bc193a25d525d717087a232)** .

Mas tarde agregare la función que ejecuta el servidor web integrado para que te evites usar apache y php

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# −*− coding: UTF−8 −*−
# Las dos lineas anteriores se aseguran #1 de localizar el 
# interpretador para poder usar el script directamente
# y #2 de definir la codificacion de la fuente. Solo es
# buena educacion, =)

#import sys              # con argparse y la linea shebang! (#!) ya no lo ocupas
import argparse          # modulo utilisimo para lineas de comando
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

def principal():
    ''' Secuencia principal a ejecutar cuando se llama desde
        la linea de comando en shell '''

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

    GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)

    pwm = GPIO.PWM(12, 100) # (1): pwm asignado pero nunca usado
    pwm2 = GPIO.PWM(11, 100)

    pwm.start(0)            # (1): Tal vez hacia falta esto?
    pwm2.start(0)

    #  vel = float(sys.argv[1])  # (6): Esto ya no es necesario,
    #  p1 = int(sys.argv[2])     # puedes hacer referencia al objeto
    #  p2 = int(sys.argv[3])     # args (linea 59) donde las propiedades
    #  p3 = int(sys.argv[4])     # corresponden a tus variables. argparse
                                 # ya se encargo de que sean del tipo correcto

    if args.verbose:
        print(args.vel)
        print(args.p1)
        print(args.p2)
        print(args.p3)

    while args.p3 != 2:
        if args.p1 == 1:                   # (2): Faltaba indentar tu bloque if para
            pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(args.vel)  # incluirlo en el bucle while
            pwm2.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
        elif args.p2 == 1:                 # (3): Revisa tu logica. la condicion
            pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(0)         # elif esta en una variable distinta al
            pwm2.ChangeDutyCycle(args.vel) # if original! seguro que asi debe ser?
    # (4): Este bucle if es infinito, el valor de p3 nunca cambiara!

    pwm.stop()
    GPIO.cleanup()
    print("fin")

if __name__ == '__main__':  # (5) Recurso idiomatico en python: de esta manera
                            # te aseguras que el programa se pueda ejecutar desde
                            # el shell, o que igual se pueda incluir como modulo
                            # en otro porgrama mas grande, mandando llamar al
                            # metodo principal()

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Mi programa para controlar motores \
                                    con la Raspberry PI')
    parser.add_argument('vel', type=float, help='velocidad (punto flotante)')
    parser.add_argument('p1', type=int, help='velocidad (punto flotante)')
    parser.add_argument('p2', type=int, help='velocidad (punto flotante)')
    parser.add_argument('p3', type=int, help='velocidad (punto flotante)')
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', dest='verbose', action='store_true',
                        help='genera salida explicita (opcional)')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    principal()
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, justo ahora lo corregiré, el valor de p3 tenia la intención de cambiarlo cuando se presionara un botón de stop en mi interfaz de html, y si, estoy usando apache + php. Por cierto, desconocía el servidor web integrado de python, gracias por el dato.

Comment: El módulo es HTTPSimpleServer forma parte de la librería estándar ( baterías incluídas! Python=amor) no he tenido oportunidad de modificar tu código para correr su propio webserver, pero no deben ser más de 10 líneas de código adicionales incluyendo el handler de la forma. Tal vez por la noche lo pueda hacer, tu código me recordó mis primeros proyectos de robótica en la escuela de ingeniería en los 90s. Claro que eran en FORTRAN y con unas tarjetas Galil para controlar los motores, pero escencialmente es el mismo ejercicio jeje

Comment: intente utilizar rutas absolutas en mi programa php, y también corregí el programa en python, colocándole algunas de las lineas de código de tu programa, pero no hay comunicación. estoy aferrado con utilizar apache y php con html por dos razones, una creo que es mas estético, y dos, es el objetivo temporal de mi materia en la escuela. de todas formas gracias por tu codigo, me funciono de maravilla.....no habia visto tu comentario anterior, un pregunta, utilizar el servidor web de python se puede hacer igual de estético con html al igual que con php?

Comment: Si el requerimiento es que ambos programas de comuniquen, te recomiendo que uses un fifo. Es un archivo especial que se crea con el comando mkfifo en tu Shell. (fifo=first-in-first-out) conectas el stdout de apache al fifo, y ya sea el stdin de Python o un lo abres como archivo regular con sys.open()  mismo fifo, y todo lo que escriba apache en el fifo, lo leerá Python al instante p.ej: `mkfifo mififo-es-espectacular; php script.php>> mififo-es-espectacular &` , luego en otra línea de comando o incluso otra terminal `cat mififo-es-espectacular | programa.py` es como rabbitmq de los pobres

Comment: eh estado investigando y uno de mis problemas es que para que php reciba algo primero se tiene que terminar el programa en python, y tal como me habias se;alado el ciclo while es infinito, pero eso ya lo arregle, ahora mi duda es que si el archivo fifo me puede permitir enviar datos de php a python sin la necesidad de esperar a que se termine el programa,para ser mas especifico poder ejecutar el archivo python y estar cambiando el valor de sus variables mientras se realiza el ciclo while.

Comment: eh estado investigando y uno de mis problemas es que para que php reciba algo primero se tiene que terminar el programa en python, y tal como me habias se;alado el ciclo while es infinito, pero eso ya lo arregle, ahora mi duda es que si el archivo fifo me puede permitir enviar datos de php a python sin la necesidad de esperar a que se termine el programa,para ser mas especifico poder ejecutar el archivo python y estar cambiando el valor de sus variables mientras se realiza el ciclo while.

Comment: Es correcto. El fifo es para ambos programas un archivo cualquiera suceptible de ser abierto y cerrado independientemente por cada uno de los programas, siempre y cuando sean ejecutados desde procesos distintos ( no ejecutes el programa en Python con una llamada desde php pues eso generará un subproceso que debe terminar para que continúe el proceso principal  por eso te recomendaba ejecutar los programas desde terminales distintas, asegurando la independencia de procesos. Que hay en el archivo fifo? Los últimos bytes que haya escrito un programa y que otro programa no haya leído.

Comment: Por eso es first in first out o en español, "PEPS" primeras entradas , primeras salidas . Checa el manual : `man mkfifo` si necesitas comunicación bidireccional, la respuesta es crear 2 fifos: uno para datos de php->Python y el otro para Python->php. El sentido del flujo de datos lo determina que programa conectar el fifo a su stdout y cuál lo conecta a su stdin. Fuera de eso, todas las operaciones de archivos estándar (open, close, seek) aplican para el fifo como si fuera un archivo común y corriente.

Comment: bueno, trate utilizando json para php  python y si hay cominicacion, ya es un logro, pero lo que no entiendo es porque no se ejecuta el resto del programa de mi archivo de python, solo un parte

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de utilizar PHP nativo en lugar de hacer llamadas Python. Se puede acceder directamente a los puertos GPIO desde PHP utilizando funcions fwrite() en lugar de utilizar llamadas a sistema shell_exec(). Yo he preparado una librería para el uso de los LEDS de esta manera. Es muy corta y fácil de entender, por lo que con poco código la podrías modificar a tus necesidades. Te ahorras de tener que programar en diferentes lenguajes, instalaciones extras y tiempos de espera utilizando shell_exec(). De acuerdo que no es tan rápido como el Python, pero creo que en este caso te podría servir: https://rafamartin10.blogspot.com/2021/08/clase-en-php-para-encenderapagar-led-en.html